# How do I access JSON encoded array in php

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, json

Let's say I have this.

```
$myArray = array(
        'userAgent' => $u_agent,
        'name'      => $bname,
        'version'   => $version,
        'platform'  => $platform,
        'pattern'    => $pattern
    );
```

Then I encode it,

$bar = json_encode($myArray);

Now If I were to `echo $bar;` and pass it back to ajax, I could access each array object like so.

```
success: function(data)
         { 
            var name = data.name;
            var platform= data.platform;
```

How can I access each one in php AFTER it's been encoded in JSON?

Comment: Just access the array `$myArray` that you built it from, or if you are talking about dealing with JSON sent in subsequent request, just `json_decode()` it.

Comment: You don't access json-encoded data. json is a transport/communications format. You decode it back to a native data structure, and access that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$bar=json_decode($bar, true); 
print_r($bar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code (index.php) and it is working fine in my end. I believe that you need to parse JSON before you get data in your ajax success function.

```
<?php
if($_GET){
$myArray = array(
    'userAgent' => "FF",
    'name'      => "Asik",
    'version'   => "1.0",
    'platform'  => "Windows",
    'pattern'    => ""
);

echo json_encode($myArray);
exit;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url:"index.php?getResponse=true",success:function(result){
      result = JSON.parse(result);
      $("#div1").html(result.name);
    }});
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```